# Why Class 'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider' not found in laravel 7.0?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, laravel-7

I installed package  **composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3**
After installation,

Added `Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class` to `'providers'` array.

Added `'AWS' => Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade::class,` to `'aliases'` array.

When I am trying to execute `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider"`

its throwing error :

```php
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider' not found
```

**I have already done `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload`**

then error is `"In ProviderRepository.php line 208`:

```
Class 'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider' not found

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1"
```

Comment: `Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider` does not exist in that package.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter then what should I do ?

Comment: I think you've installed the wrong package, try https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

Comment: @DigitalDrifter but its already mention on laravel documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites    please check. and help me

Comment: Ok, try installing the package I mentioned also with that one.